# WSO2 ESB REST Post request empty response

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to call test Rest Api via Post request but ESB returns always empty response. For GET request response is sent correctly by ESB.

I have tried almost everything but still cannot make this work. My ultimate goal is to store message sent by client via Post request (large requests) and sent XML structured response to user that message is queued. Here's simple example what I have tried but for Post request empty response is sent by ESB.

```
<inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<log>
  <property name="text" value="IN Sequence"></property>
</log>
<header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"></header>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
  <format>
        <response xmlns="">Hello world</response>
  </format>
</payloadFactory>
<send></send>
</inSequence>
```

Is this BUG In WSO2 ESB 4.0.8 or am I missing something ?

Thanks,
Kari

Comment: Can you post logs after enabling wire logs of ESB. You can enable wire logs by referring to mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved. Actually problem was that in Rest client I didn't specify Content-type. After adding Content-Type application/xml -header. The XML response worked fine for POST request. For GET Request this was working all the time.